# Parse - querying createdAt column gives no result

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to query my parse class for the "createdAt" column to get the number of parse objects that are created after a specific date. For this I create a 7 days ago date and sends it to the parse cloud function as a parameter:

```
public void getAdsFromServer() {
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
    Log.i(LOG, "date before 7 days = " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    params.put("createdAt", sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getNumOfAds", params,
            new FunctionCallback<Integer>() {
                public void done(Integer result, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.i(LOG, "SUCCESS:: " + result.toString());
                    } else {
                        Log.i(LOG, "failure");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Following is my Parse cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getNumOfAds", function(request, response) {
   var query = new Parse.Query("Ad");
   query.greaterThan("createdAt", request.params.createdAt);
   query.find({
     success: function(results) {
       response.success(results.length);
     },
     error: function() {
       response.error("ad lookup failed");
     }
   });
});
```

Although The "Ad" class on Parse is populated with more than 15 records newer than this date, `Log.i(LOG, "SUCCESS:: " + result.toString());` prints out "SUCCESS:: 0".
I guess my date formatting is wrong, but all my web search shows this is the Parse Date formatting.

Even when logging:

```
final ParseObject ad = new ParseObject("Ad");
Log.i(LOG, "Parse object created at: " + ad.getCreatedAt());
```

I get this format.

Would appreciate your help to find out what is wrong in my code.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can pass in a native Date object and Parse will handle that and use it as a JavaScript date on the server correctly. That's how the other parts of the API work, so I can't see why this would be different.

Comment: I finally solved it. Thanks anyway!